# Change width of menu items depending on amount of menu items

Tags: javascript, css, joomla, menuitem, responsive

Using Joomla I have got 4 menu items. One of them is optional. If I want to unpublish this menu item, the other menu items width should be increased, but only at viewport min-width 980px.
The menu has the id #menu, the elements width I want to change is #menu li. The menu item which is optional has .optMenuitem as its classname. For four menu items the width should be 25%, for three 33.33% than. 
I thought of sth like:

```js
function changeWidth (){
 var four = document.getElementsByClassName('optMenuitem');
 var opt = document.getElementByID('menu');
 if (four==true){
  opt.li.style.width = "25%";
 } else {
  opt.li.style.width = "33.33%";
 }
}
```

Does not work. I'm a newbie. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the console show an error?

Comment: I meant yes. "opt.li" is undefined. How do I target the #menu li element to change it's width?

Comment: What happends exactly, are they all at 25%? Can you show the HTML of the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target `#menu li` you should do something like this:

```js
function changeWidth() {
  var four = document.getElementsByClassName('optMenuitem');
  // You select all the menu items
  var opt = document.querySelectorAll('#menu li');
  if (four == true) {
    // You loop on all of them and you set the width
    for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++)
      opt[i].style.width = "25%";
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < opt.length; i++)
      opt[i].style.width = "33%";
  }
}
```

Comment: that's the (almost) perfect solution and it's working. Thanks! Last but not least: I only want to change the width, if the viewports min-width is 980px. Is that possible too?

Comment: @RicardoMüller yes you can, simply add a test to see if the width of screen is bigger or not than 980 px and apply your logic .. you can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window and you will see a lot of method to get the window width

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** I added simple JS to show you how to add classes to elements

If you're not against using **[flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**, here is the solution.

The only drawback of flexboxes is that **[they work on recent browsers and not old ones](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)**.

Anyway, here is the answer (I will give you the CSS + HTML and I'll let you handle the JS side, you will just have to apply the class to your menu items and add/delete them on demand)

```js
const containers = document.getElementsByClassName('container');

for (let container of containers) {
  for (const item of container.children) {
    item.className += ' menu';
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.menu {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgrey;
  
  /* Just to align them to center and style them */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-left: -1px;
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Menu 1</div>
  <div>Menu 2</div>
  <div>Menu 3</div>
  <div>Menu 4</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>Menu 1</div>
  <div>Menu 2</div>
  <div>Menu 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you may consider your code with `ul li` so it's more suitable for menu items ;)

Comment: And if we do it HTML5 style, I should also use the `nav` tag for my container. That's your opinion, mine is that lists need more styling to look like that. Whatever floats your boat ;)

Comment: the problem is that the html is generated automatically. I think this would work fine, but in regard to Joomla it's awkward

Comment: Well all you need in this case is a class. I don't know joomla that much, but I guess you can at least give your automatically generated element a class  ?

Comment: no, the system give the class by itself. But every single Element in for example a menu will get it's own class. It's more likely an ID than a class, but it is declarated as a class.

Comment: I have edited my post to show you how to add classes to your elements. All you need to do is know the class / ID of your menu container, and voilà !